# PHP - Add and stack a value with a session

Tags: php, variables, parameters, get

Let's say I have a `$variable`, which contains the word "hey" and a link with a GET parameter.

> HTML

```
 <a href="mywebsite.php?add=true">Link</a>
```

> PHP

```
 $var = "hey";

 if ($_GET['add'] == 'true') {
      $var .= "2";
      echo $var;
 }
```

When I click on the link, it will add "2" to the variable value "hey", so the 
output is: hey2.
Is there a way of keep adding (**stacking**) the numbers on click with **pure PHP**?

If i click again, I'd like to have **hey22**, **hey222** (...)

**EDIT: It looks like it isn't going to work with variables, so the best answer goes to** *@Bunker Boy* **because he solved it with sessions.**

Comment: you want to hold a value with help of variable on the different php call, i don't think so you can get your desired output with the help of variable because on every call php start a new execution that store new variable, you must store the value anywhere may be in the db or session

Comment: Do you know how I should do this with sessions?

Comment: let me try, i ll be back

Comment: @BunkerBoy thanks for your effort.. take your time

Comment: tell me one thing that this click can be infinite ? i mean the php call ?

Comment: What do you mean by infinite? It doesn't matter how many times you click on it, i'd like to add a number everytime the link is clicked @BunkerBoy

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Syno try this:

> // mywebsite.html

```
<a href="mywebsite.php?add=true">Link</a>
```

> //mywebsite.php

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION["var"])){
    if ($_GET['add'] == 'true') {
          $_SESSION["var"] .= "2";
          echo $_SESSION["var"];
    }
 }
 else{
    $_SESSION["var"] = "hey";
     if ($_GET['add'] == 'true') {
          $_SESSION["var"] .= "2";
          echo $_SESSION["var"];
     }
 }
```

Comment: My hero :D Thank you sir

Comment: Not the most efficient way to do it though.

Comment: @Syno you can use this way until you will not get the better way

Comment: @clearshot66  we can not say any answer to most efficient answer  because there are millions of way for a single logic

Comment: There sure are millions of other ways. BunkerBoy's solution helped me the most since I've posted my question. If you, clearshot66, have another solution, please let me know because i'm curious how ;)